# definition of norm and $\ell_2$ norm

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

This is from my textbook:
[image]

[image]

I am pretty sure when we have a norm function for a vector, for example $v=(3,4)$, so $\|v\| = 5$, which is the euclidean distance, so why the '2' is deleted rather than  $\left \| v \right \|_2=5$?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your textbook explicitly says that the Euclidean distance is *not* the only possible norm. When context is clear (e.g., it's obvious given the context that the Euclidean norm, say, is used) then the subscript $2$ of $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ may be dropped; since there is no ambiguity. If there *is* any risk of ambiguity, then one should always be explicit with regard to the norm used, i.e. write explicitly $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$, $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$, $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$,  $\lVert\cdot\rVert_F$, etc.

Comment: @Clement C.   So the subscript can be dropped if there is no ambiguity? I thought we have to always use subscript like a standard format

Comment: Mathematicians, like everyone, are lazy: if they can avoid extra notation when there is no ambiguity, most of them will.

Comment: Given $v=(3,4)$ and $||v||=5$. This $||v||$ is Euclidean norm which is also called the Euclidean length, L2 distance, ℓ2 distance, L2 norm, or ℓ2 norm. See the section of Euclidean norm on this webpage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)